# Help them don't make mistake or Help them not make mistake?

Tags: sentence-choice

Which one is correct?

> - Parents are more experienced than their children so they can help them **don't make mistake** in their life.
> - Parents are more experienced than their children so they can help them **not make mistake** in their life.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please [edit] your question to include more detail. Why are you having trouble choosing between these two options? What do you already know about using “do not”? People can write better answers if the understand what you already know and what is still confusing for you.

Comment: Mtra, Welcome to the site. Can you tell us the context of the statement? Neither is perfect, but the second one is closer.

Comment: I reopened the question because you included complete sentence examples. However, please be sure to explain why you are confused or concerned. This way, users can address your specific problem. Otherwise, your post may be closed again as "lacking details/research". See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.